# how to access multiple array elements in blade file laravel

Tags: arrays, laravel, object, eloquent-relationship

[image: Output]

**Rating** model

```
class Rating extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'owner_id', 'toilet_id','user_id','rating','desc',
    ];

    public function toilet()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ToiletInfo::class);
    }
}
```

**ToiletInfo** model

```
class ToiletInfo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'owner_id', 'toilet_name','price','complex_name','address','toilet_lat','toilet_lng','status',
    ];

    public function owner()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(ToiletOwner::class);
    }

    public function ratings()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Rating::class,'toilet_id');
    }
}
```

**RatingController**

```
public function index()
{

    return $toilets = ToiletInfo::with('ratings')->get();

    //return view('admin.rating',compact('toilets'));
}
```

[image]

I want to get the average of *rating* but how to access elements inside **ratings[]**

Or help me improve the method I am using to get ratings for toilets that are reviewed by users

Comment: `ratings` is an array, you should retrieve elements by calling its indexes or another `foreach`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I understand from your question you want to get the average rating.

In your `ToiletInfo` model, add a new method:

```
public function getAverageRating()
{
    $ratings = $this->ratings;
    $count = $ratings->count(); // total count
    $total_ratings = $ratings->sum('rating'); // add the 'rating' for all rows
    return $total_ratings / $count; // average

}
```

In your blade file, you can simply do

```
$toilet->getAverageRating()
```

Which will give the average rating.

Comment: This works good but newly registered toilet faced divide by 0 exception.. so added: `if ($count>0) 
            return $total_ratings / $count; // average
        
        else
            return 0;
        `